# Emberjs partial's action doesnt fire in component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I try to extend a component (https://github.com/ember-addons/ember-forms) to make it possible to add extra button next to the form controls.

**The idea**

developer passes an extra property to the component, and a partial will be rendered next to the form control (input, select, textarea).

**Problem**

It works fine but if i have a partial with some action, the action wont fire.

**JsBin**

Here is a simplified JsBin which demonstrates the problem: http://jsbin.com/pexolude/105/edit

**html**

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Component test</h2>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{booh-whaa partial="somebutton"}}
  <h3>This partial's action works</h3>
  {{partial "somebutton"}}
  </script>

   <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='_somebutton'>
  <button {{action "booh"}} >Hit me!</button>
</script>

     <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='components/booh-whaa'>
  <h3>This is my component</h3>
  {{partial partial}}
</script>
```

**JS.**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  selectedCategory:null,
  actions: {
    booh: function() {
      alert("booh!");
    } 
  }
});

App.BoohWhaaComponent = Ember.Component.extend({

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Knownasilya said, actions inside a component are, by default, handled by the component. However, If you specify the target on the action helper, the action with automatically propagate and you don't have to use `sendAction()`.

In your case, this is as simple as:

```
{{action 'booh' target='controller'}}
```

Or if the action is on the route's view:

```
{{action 'booh' target='parentView'}}
```

Another option is to use [Em.TargetActionSupport](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TargetActionSupport.html) to send actions with contexts and other arguments to specific targets throughout your app.

Answer (score 0):

When you fire an action inside a component, that component handles the action. If you want it to continue, use `this.sendAction('action')` and then on your component set `{{booh-whaa action='booh'}}`. See the [guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/handling-user-interaction-with-actions/) for more information about actions in components.

Here's a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/pexolude/107/).

Also partials no longer require an underscore.