# EmberJS: Nothing handled the action

Tags: ember.js

I'm an Ember beginner, using 2.3.0.  To an existing application I need to add a button that toggles content on and off the screen.  Following the existing code patterns, I added the following two files.

**app/components/help.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {
      toggleHelp() {
          this.toggleProperty('isShowingHelp');
      }
    }
});
```

**templates/components/help.hbs**

```
<div class="help">
    <a href="#" {{action "toggleHelp"}}>help</a>
</div>
{{#if this.isShowingHelp}}
  <p>HELPHELPHELP</p>
{{/if}}
```

And then in various *.hbs files I'm adding `{{partial "components/help"}}` to get the button to show up where it is needed.

The button renders as expected as

```
<div class="help">
    <a href="#" data-ember-action="493">help</a>
</div>
```

But when I click, I get the error, "Nothing handled the action 'toggleHelp'. If you did handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble."

I checked the [Ember documentation](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/templates/actions/) and saw that this matches the instructions.

I think the issue might be because I am calling it as a `partial`, but none of the other options (`view`, `render`, `outlet`) seems to apply to my limited case.

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24544103/1149759), I tried `{{action "toggleHelp" target='component'}}`, but then the error when I click turned into, "ember.debug.js:29112 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined."

What am I missing here?

### Update

If I copy `toggleHelp` into the controller going along with one of the .hbs files, then the link works properly.  But surely the right way cannot be to put this in multiple controller files?  (And when I try to put `toggleHelp` in controllers/application.js, in hopes that would cover everywhere (?!), I'm back to the original error.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is indeed `{{partial "components/help"}}`!

In general you should not use partials. To call a component you use `{{component-name}}`.

However components in Ember 2.3 need to have a `-` in their name. So `help` is *not* valid!

rename your component into something like `my-help`. So `app/components/my-help.js` for your js and `templates/components/my-help.hbs`. Then you can just do `{{my-help}}` to use the component.

Comment: Argh.  I did try `{{help}}` at one point, and that didn't work.  I would have never figured out that hyphen thing in a zillion years.  THANK YOU.